# How to create the settings file from default options?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, settings

`File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)` is false.

How to make it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Configuration file and the Settings are not the same thing. The configuration file is the one named `[Appname].exe.config` that should be in the same location as the application.

The settings are stored in the user store separately, and I'm not aware of any method to check if they exist by a file name anyway.

Comment: Edited the title and removed the app-config tag to make it clearer

Comment: Umm... you are still testing for a Configuration file. That has nothing at all to do with the settings.

Comment: Even if you are right, I'm only interested in making that assertion to become true anyway. But I don't want to create an empty file in that path. The file must contain the Settings XML.

Comment: You need an `app.config` file in a VS project (or an applicationname.exe.config file in the binary's dir) to make that test return true, as I already suggested by my answer. But again, that is not affected at all by settings saved/not saved in code. (though usually in VS, binding settings will create an app.config for you if you don't already have one - but still, saving settings does not)

Comment: +1, this answer is correct.  I guess he wants something else but I can't reverse-engineer it either.

Comment: @Andrew Barber, you said twice that the app.config is located in the same directory as the binary, and this seems to be true when you are debugging and installing the app. But you'll notice that the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` points to the `AppData` folder in some cases.

Comment: @XMLForDummies: ConfigurationFile != Settings. Just to re-re-reiterate... 'The Configuration file and the Settings are not the same thing.'